# Batch canvas resize (add 1 inch of blank canvas to the top of all images)

Tags: resize, automation, batch-processing

What is the most efficient way to add X amount of blank canvas to the top of a bunch of images? I'm sure there's a program capable of doing a batch process somewhere. But so far all I've found is batch programs that will resize all canvases to the same size; I don't want that, as in this case all images are different dimensions. I have access to GIMP ifranView and Photoshop, though I'd have to dig out my Photoshop CD and reinstall it.

Answer (score 4):

Dig out that Photoshop CD, which includes Adobe Bridge if it's CS or later, or set up a free trial of Creative Cloud and download Photoshop. This is really easy to do.

- Record an Action in Photoshop that adds a *relative* amount (percentage, pixels, inches, whatever) to the top of the canvas. Any of the images you'll be modifying will do. Then either:
- In Bridge, select all the images you want to modify. From `Tools > Photoshop > Batch...` select the action you recorded, to be performed on each selected image.

or

- In Photoshop choose `File > Automate > Batch...`, which gives you the same dialog. You'll have to browse to select the images.
- Run the batch.

You're done.